# Any good methods to change the color of the background faster in C?

Tags: c, windows, background-color

I want to colorize everywhere on the console background with different colors every time I press the key, but the problem is that it just too slow.I think it is the loop that causes the problem. Is there any way to speed up the print or any better method to color the background? Below is an example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define width 189
#define border 50

void setfullscreen()
{
    keybd_event(VK_MENU,0x38,0,0);
    keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0x1c,0,0);
    keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0x1c,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
    keybd_event(VK_MENU,0x38,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
}
void setcursor(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE output =GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pos = {x,y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output,pos);
}

int main()
{
    setfullscreen();
    int x=getch();
    int count=3;
    while(1)
    {
        x=getch();
        for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<border;j++)
            {
                count++;
                if(j<border/2)
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),count);
                    setcursor(i,j);
                    printf(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),count+50);
                    setcursor(i,j);
                    printf(" ");
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputattribute

Comment: could you give me an example? I search for it but still don't understand how to use it.